# How to sort a list in ascending order of string index in java

Tags: java, android, string

I've created a list in java as following :

```
1   bbbb london
1.1 aaaa nyc
1.10 cccc jaipur
...
1.2 test test
1.11 test1 test1
```

I need to sort it based on index 1,1.1,1.2 etc! These are string values.

Like:

```
1   bbbb london
1.1 aaaa nyc
1.2 test test
...
1.10 cccc jaipur
1.11 test1 test1
```

How can i do that?

Initially the index was float but in-order to get 1.10 in list i changed index to string so `Collection.sort(list)` doesnt give output as expected.

My purpose is like to create a numbered bullets like

```
1 Helo
 1.1 helo1
 1.2 helo2
 1.3 hello3
2 Test
 2.1 Test1
 2.2 Test2
3 World
```

Any help please?

Comment: I recommend having separate fields for the major and minor indices.

Comment: @NicholasK . It can only be 1 - 1.1 - 1.2 ... 1.10 - 1.11 - 2 - 2.1 - 2.2 blah blah. Its like adding intermediate points between two main points. Like numbered bullets

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. But if i create another indices with float value the 1.10 will change to 1.1 and their will be two 1.1 and sorting will get wrong right?

Comment: You might have a working answer below.  From a data model point of view, it is generally bad to store numbers as strings.

Comment: Check out this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617214/java-how-to-sort-an-array-of-strings-that-contain-periods-dots-without-extend

Answer (score 5):

Given the list :

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1.32   bbbb london", "21.1 aaaa nyc", 
                                  "100.10 cccc jaipur", "1.2 test test",
                                  "1.11 test1 test1");
```

You can write your own custom comparator as shown below :

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return Float.compare(Float.parseFloat(o1.split(" ")[0]),
                             Float.parseFloat(o2.split(" ")[0]));
    }
});
```

Here, we split the String by `" "` and fetch the *floating* part of the string which happens to be the first *index* of the array. Now we parse it to a float and compare it with the second string.

If you are on `java-8` you could do it one line :

```
Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> 
      Float.compare(Float.parseFloat(o1.split(" ")[0]), Float.parseFloat(o2.split(" ")[0])));
```

Comment: `Collections.sort(mRoute.getWayPointList(), new Comparator<WayPoint>() {
            public int compare(WayPoint o1, WayPoint o2) {
                return Float.compare(Float.parseFloat(o1.getId().split(" ")[0]),
                        Float.parseFloat(o2.getId().split(" ")[0]));
            }
        });`

Actualy i tried this still no it is not sorting! elements in List is added through a model Waypoint! I Could get the index(id) using that model.getId

Comment: Is the String stored in the field `id`? If possible do share the class Waypoint

Comment: This answer does not work. Yet it has 4 votes. My answer works and it has -1 votes. It's funny :)

Comment: @PrasadKarunagoda : This solution does work. Please go ahead and try it. As mentioned in the comments by OP, probably he is not using it correctly as there is a model class `Waypoint`. That's the reason I've asked him to share the file if possible. Meanwhile you could try out the answer for yourself.

Comment: @NicholasK, I tried your code on the input data provided in the question. And it does not give the answer expected in the question. I think the point you are missing is, Dillz's requirement is not for a "natural" ordering. That's why it does not work as String nor float.

Comment: What are you talking about? I believe you haven't understood the question. It is sorting it out based on the floating values present in each string in ascending order. This is the output received `1 fd
1.11 test1 test1
1.2 test test
1.32 cccc jaipur
1.34 aaaa nyc
1.39   bbbb london
` Notice how the strings are sorted in ascending order based on the float(numbers) present in the string.

Comment: @NicholasK, But the expected output in the question is `1`, `1.1`, `1.2`, `1.10`, `1.11`. Did you notice that `1.2` comes **before** `1.10` in the expected output? But in your program `1.2` comes **after** `1.10`.

Comment: I believe that's to illustrate another example. Notice how he separates them by a `...`

Answer (score -1):

Try this. This should work. Main logic is in `compareTo` method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Sort
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new Entry("1", "bbbb london"));
    entries.add(new Entry("1.1", "aaaa nyc"));
    entries.add(new Entry("1.10", "cccc jaipur"));
    entries.add(new Entry("1.2", "test test"));
    entries.add(new Entry("1.11", "test1 test1"));

    Collections.sort(entries);
    for (Entry e : entries)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}

class Entry implements Comparable<Entry>
{
  String index;
  String value;
  int major;
  int minor;

  Entry(String index, String value)
  {
    this.index = index;
    this.value = value;

    String[] array = index.split("\\.");
    if (array.length == 2)
    {
      major = Integer.valueOf(array[0]);
      minor = Integer.valueOf(array[1]);
    }
    else if (array.length == 1)
    {
      major = Integer.valueOf(array[0]);
    }
    else
    {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid index : " + index);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Entry otherEntry)
  {
    if (this.major < otherEntry.major)
    {
      return -1;
    }
    else if (this.major > otherEntry.major)
    {
      return 1;
    }
    else
    {
      if (this.minor < otherEntry.minor)
      {
        return -1;
      }
      else if (this.minor > otherEntry.minor)
      {
        return 1;
      }
      else
      {
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return index + " " + value;
  }
}
```